# fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda5

Tags: boot

I am using **Ubuntu v20.04 in VMBox over Windows10**
I had recently **moved my .vhd file to new drive in windows and increased its size**.

After that I am not able to start this .vhd in VM box.

It seems like the **Ubuntu is enable to identify the partition**.
After digging a bit and trying to access it with and iso image, I have reached to a point the i**ssues seems to be with corrupted super block and  magic number**

fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda5

I **tried to use the backup magic numbers** but those too are not helping

```
**ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -b 98304 /dev/sda5
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda5

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

/dev/sda5 contains a ext4 file system**
```

Can someone please help me to correct this issue. I ***have my 4 weeks work in this partition.***
Please help me to retrieve this drive

Comment: Use an Unbuntu installation image ('Try Ubuntu' mode) in your VM: run gparted to access the problematic vhd (set as second HDD in Virtualbox(?)). See if you can figure out - might be you can do a fsck at least, was that resize successful, did you resize a partition to match?

Comment: Did you try running e2fsck with an alternate/older backup superblock?